# download files with php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file, download

I am creating a web application in which files are going to be uploaded to a mysql table and may i say that this is the first time i use code to upload/download files. I am facing a problem concerning the downloading procedure. When the link to download the file is pressed, the page displays the files rather than downloading it, which is what i want it to do.
To upload the files to mysql i use the code below:

```
$fileName = $_FILES['nomarxia']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['nomarxia']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['nomarxia']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['nomarxia']['type'];
$fp       = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content  = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content  = addslashes($content);

fclose($fp);

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}

include 'library/config.php';
include 'library/opendb.php';
$query = "INSERT INTO files VALUES ('', 'ERGO', '".$ame."','ΝΟΜΑΡΧΙΑ','".$fileName."', '".$fileSize."', '".$fileType."', '".$content."')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
```

To view the files i use the code below:

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, doc_type FROM files WHERE user_id='".$ame."' AND user_type='".$user_type."'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result1) {
        echo'<span>Πρόβλημα</span>';
        $message  = 'Λάθος Ερώτημα: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Ολόκληρο το ερώτημα: ' . $sql;
        die($message);
        echo'</br><input type="button" value="Επιστροφή" onclick="history.go(-1);"/>';
        echo '</span>';
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result1) == 0) {
        echo'Το σύστημα δεν τηρεί κανένα αρχείο για την εταιρεία με Α.Μ.Ε. '.$ame.'</br><input type="button" value="Επιστροφή" onclick="history.go(-1);"/></br>';           
    } else {
        echo'<strong>Α.Μ.Ε. => '.$ame.'</strong></br></br>';
        while (list($id, $doc_type) = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    ?>
        <a href=download.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $doc_type;?></a></br>
```

And now where the problem is....To download the file i use this code:

```
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM files WHERE id ='".$id."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            echo'<span>Πρόβλημα</span>';
            $message  = 'Λάθος Ερώτημα: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
            $message .= 'Ολόκληρο το ερώτημα: ' . $sql;
            die($message);
            echo'</br><input type="button" value="Επιστροφή" onclick="history.go(-1);"/>';
            echo '</span>';
        } else {
            list($name, $type, $size, $content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            header('Content-length: $size');
            header('Content-type: $type');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name');
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            echo $content;
            include 'library/closedb.php';
            exit;
        }
```

Is there anything that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Change this: `header('Content-length: $size'); header('Content-type: $type'); header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name');`

To: `header("Content-length: $size"); header("Content-type: $type");  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");`

Comment: Are you using output-buffering? So you have to call `ob_flush();` after `echo $content;` to send the content to the browser.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Tried to change the single quote to double but the problem persists!!!! Any other hints???

Comment: @mario.klump tried your advice but there was no impovement. Still the browser displays the file and doesn't download it. Any more suggestions???

Comment: Ok. Try this script: `header('Content-type: txt');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=1.txt');
echo 1111;`. It is working right? Then check this: `$id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM files WHERE id ='".$id."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query); 
            header("Content-type: $type");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name"); echo $content;`. If this not working try to print variables: $name, $type, $content. Oh! The problem can be in encoding.